# Real function vector space properties verification

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing a self study on linear algebra and I am trying to solve the following exercise.

> If the sum of the "vectors" $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $\mathbf{F}$ (the vector space of all real functions) is defined as $f(g(x))$, then the "zero vector" is $g(x)=x$. Keep the usual scalar multiplications $cf(x)$, and find two rules that are broken.

Equations that is true according to the exercise:

1. $f(x)+g(x) = f(g(x))$ and subsequently $g(x) + f(x) = g(f(x))$ (**eq. 1**)
2. $g(x)=x$ (**eq. 2**)

---

**The rules are:**

1. $x + y = y + x$.
2. $x + (y + z) = (x + y) + z$.
3. There is a unique "zero vector" such that $x + 0 = x$ for all $x$.
4. For each x there is a unique vector $-x$ such that $x + (-x) = 0$.
5. $1x = x$
6. $(c_1c_2)x = c_1(c_2x)$
7. $c(x+y)=cx+cy$
8. $(c_1+c_2)x=c_1x+c_2x$

---

1. According to rule `1` we should have:
   $$f(x)+g(x)=g(x)+f(x) \overset{eq.~1}{\iff} f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$$ 
   Thus, rule `1` is **broken**.
2. According to rule `2` we should have:
   $$f(x) + (g(x)+h(x)) = (f(x)+g(x))+h(x) \overset{eq.~1}{\iff} f(x) + g(h(x)) = f(g(x))+h(x) \overset{eq.~1}{\iff} f(g(h(x))) = f(g(h(x)))$$ 
   Thus, rule `2` is **not-broken**.
3. According to rule `3` we should have:
   $$f(x)+\underbrace{g(x)}_\text{zero term} = f(x)\overset{eq.~2}{\iff}f(x)+x = f(x)$$ Thus, rule `3` is **broken**.
4. According to rule `4` we should have:
   $$f(x)+(-f(x)) = 0 \overset{eq.~1}{\iff} f(-f(x))=0$$ **I couldn't make a deduction for this**.
5. According to rule `5` we should have:
   $$1f(x)=f(x)$$ Thus, rule `5` is **not-broken**.
6. According to rule `6` we should have:
   $$(c_1c_2)f(x)=c_1(c_2f(x))$$ Thus, rule `6` is **not-broken**.
7. According to rule `7` we should have:
   $$c(f(x)+g(x))=cf(x)+cg(x) \overset{eq.~1}{\iff} cf(g(x))=cf(cg(x))$$ Thus, rule `7` is **broken**.
8. According to rule `8` we should have:
   $$(c_1+c_2)f(x)=c_1f(x)+c_2f(x) \overset{eq.~1}{\iff}(c_1+c_2)f(x)=c_1f(c_2f(x))$$ Thus, rule `8` is **broken**.

**Could you please help me to correct possible wrong answers?**

Thanks in advance! :)

<sup>If that matters, I would like to note that this is not an exercise for a course but for a personal pursue:)</sup>

Comment: the sum ought to be commutative, and map composition isn't

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you please explain a litle more?

Comment: the **eq.1** is enough to settle the question about: is this set a vector space?

Comment: @janmarqz now I see your point janmarqz - `the sum ought to be commutative, and map composition isn't `. So the set is not a vector space. Am I right?

Comment: : ) yes : ) : )

Comment: @janmarqz I would like to ask something irrelevant to the specific post. Having a real function vector space $\mathbf{F}$ with $f\in\mathbf{F}$ and the eight rules to hold, is there any interest to investigate if the $f^{-1}$ define a subspace? Thanks!

Comment: $f^{-1}$ will define a subset (or the empty set) in the $f$'s domain. Which domain do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rule 3: Additive identity**

I don't know if you interpreted the definition of the vector addition of your vector space correctly, but your reasoning for Rule 3 seems to be a bit odd.

$$f(x)+g(x)=f(x)\iff f(g(x))=f(x)$$

This holds obviously true only for $g(x)=x$, the proposed zero vector of your vector space. So rule 3 is **not broken**.

**Rule 4: Additive inverse**

It states that there exists an unique element $h(x)$ for every element $f(x)$ so that

$$f(x)+h(x)=g(x) \iff f(h(x))=g(x)$$

You could use the inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$ as $h(x)$, but this is only possible if $f(x)$ is injective, and since not all real functions are injective, it doesn't exist an additive inverse element for every element of your vector space. So rule 4 is **broken**.

---

I could not find any flaws in your reasoning for the rest of the rules.

Comment: Could you please explain a litle more why $f(x)$ should be injective so as to use $f^{-1}(x)$ as $h(x)$? Thanks for your answer:)

Comment: Because there simply does not exist a complete inverse function of $f(x)$ if $f$ is not injective. For example, $f(x)=x^2$ equals $1$ at $x=1$ and $x=-1$. suppose there exists a inverse function $f^{-1}$, what should $f^{-1}(1)$ be? $1$ or $-1$?

Comment: Ok I think I start getting into the point.